# How to secure communication in client-server?

Tags: json, node.js, express, angular

My application is based on AngularJS, totally client-side; the server is based on Express JS. For data communication I am using the http post method. When I send a http request, the server responds with data in JSON format, but all the JSON data shows in the client browser. I don't want to show JSON data in client browser.

[image: alt]

Is there any way to hide or secure json data in client browser?

Comment: Question and description are two totally different things, I see.

Comment: Don't send the data, then.

Comment: I have made a small edit to improve the readability of your question. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear and useful as possible; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What ever the response you will send, will be shown at the client-end. If you want to hide some data, you can always encrypt them and send it. One of the useful tool for such is [Crypto-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js).

User will still see the data but as it will be encrypted, he cannot understand it.

But, still it is safer not to send user-sensitive data to client-side.

Comment: Thanks bro...but can i decode data encrypted by Express js in angular?

Comment: Yes, you can. You will have to use Angular2 for that purpose. As both of them use npm.

Comment: If the answer has helped you, then tick it so that next user would know.